# Ошибка возникает при компиляции

Tags: javascript

У меня при компиляции выскакивает ошибка, что может быть?
В коде стопудово нет ошибок, пробовал скопировать из учебника прямо, как есть, не компилируется

Comment: какая ошибка? какая компиляция? js интерпретируемый, он не компилируется... где запускаете? Браузер? nodeJs? холодильник? нужно больше информации

Comment: Скорее всего это из-за программных смешариков...

Comment: на самом деле я даже не понял, как ее компилировать и просто вставил в браузер. браузер же сам по умолчанию компилирует?

Comment: вот код:<script>
console.log('program test1;');
console.log('implementation');
console.log('begin');
console.log('writeln('hello world');');
console.log('end.');
</script>

Comment: Убери блоки со стриптами

Comment: получилось так же, но без блоков со скриптами

Comment: @ИгорьМеньшенин, Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну это работа для Ф И К С И К О В.

---

**UPD**: в консоли браузера не нужно вставлять **HTML** тэги скрипта и экранировать кавычки

```
console.log('program test1;'); 
console.log('implementation'); 
console.log('begin'); 
console.log('writeln(\'hello world\');'); 
console.log('end.');
```

Comment: вот! теперь ошибка не возникает, спасибо. но код все равно не компилируется. попробую еще поразбираться. может подскажете, в какой еще компилятор можно попробовать?

Comment: Вы можете нажать на F12 и вставить его во вкладку Console :D  js не компилируется, а транслируется

Comment: @Игорь Меньшенин песочницы: https://jsfiddle.net , https://playcode.io/ ))

Comment: спасибо. попробую. и простите, что отнял время

Comment: Код логирует в консоль, и если ты нажмёшь F12 после запуска кода в песочнице, то увидишь вывод)